# What is the name of the range of cells that are actually loaded into memory in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory-management

I keep thinking it's called `Visible Range` but I doubt that's actually it.

Basically I'm trying to find out what the cells that are selected when you press CTRL+Left Arrow is called.

Comment: I'm not sure if I mean `loaded into memory` or not..I mean the ones that actually exist as opposed to the ones that can be displayed...

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with CTRL+Left Arrow, but my blind guess is that its `UsedRange` what you are looking for

Comment: Is this for VBA or something? This seems really unclear, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Mokubai No it's actually so I can explain to a user why they shouldn't change the formatting of all the cells in a sheet.

Comment: I think @nixda is right -- in VBA, the `.UsedRange` property of a worksheet seems to be what you are describing.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx

Comment: My guess is that you are talking about "Selection"   In VBA can access by Selection.Copy